# How To Add/Remove Multi Rows In jQuery And Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress theme options page, and one of the options I want to make is how to add/removes dynamic rows by that the user can make it when he want to add a block. something like this

```
<table id="block" width="350px" border="0">
    <tr>        
        <td> 1 </td><!--Nomber of the row-->
        <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>Title</label></td><!--Title of the row-->

        <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>IMG Link</label></td><!--Image of the row-->

        <td><textarea  type="textarea" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br /><label>Description</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Beside I want to make it saved to wordpress when updating are saved .

Comment: R.Karar, while this is a very old question, you're still active. So I wanted to inform you that as @manetsus realized (in a suggested edit), your imageshack link is broken. If possible, you might consider restoring the image in a sustainable way (i.e. through SO's imgur account) in order to preserve your post for eternity;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but I [posted a demo here](http://jsbin.com/axiso/).

HTML/CSS

```
<input id="addRow" type="button" value="Add Row">
<table id="block" width="350px" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td><!--Nomber of the row-->
  <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>Title</label></td><!--Title of the row-->
  <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>IMG Link</label></td><!--Image of the row-->
  <td><textarea  type="textarea" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br /><label>Description</label></td>
 </tr>
</table>

<style type="text/css"> 
#block { width: 50%; padding: 5px; }
#block td { vertical-align: top; }
</style>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var newRow = '\
  <tr>\
   <td>\
    <span class="index"></span> \
    <input id="removeRow" type="button" value="X" title="remove this row">\
   </td>\
   <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>Title</label></td><!--Title of the row-->\
   <td><input type="text" /><br /><label>IMG Link</label></td><!--Image of the row-->\
   <td><textarea  type="textarea" cols="40" rows="2"></textarea><br /><label>Description</label></td>\
  </tr>';

 $('#addRow').click(function(){
  $('#block').append(newRow);
  reIndex();
 })

 $('#removeRow').live('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  reIndex();
 })

 function reIndex(){
  $('#block').find('.index').each(function(i){
   $(this).html(i+2);
  })
 }

})
```